# Testing specific Azure Web Site Instance

Tags: asp.net, azure, integration-testing, load-balancing, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web Site configured to use multiple (2) instances:

[image: Azure Configuration]

I have a service bus that should pass messages (ie Cache Evict) between the instances.  I need to test this mechanism.

In a conventional (on premise) system I would point a browser to instance 1 (ie http://myserver1.example.com), perform an action, then point my browser to the other instance (http://myserver2.example.com) to test.

However, in Azure I can't see a way to hit a specific instance.  Is it possible?  Or is there an alternative way to to run through this test scenario (act on instance 1, ensure instance 2 behaves appropriately)?

Comment: I don't believe you can have such level of control in Azure. It's a question of load balancing and it's done automatically.

Comment: Can I take instances out of the load balancer, but still keep them alive?  That way I could preform the test by controlling which instance is in load balancer?

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/30/azure-load-balancer-new-distribution-mode/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an official way of doing this. However, you can achieve that by setting a cookie called `ARRAffinity` on your request.

Try hitting your site from any client (Chrome, Firefox, curl, httpie, etc) and inspect the response headers that you are getting back.

For example in `curl` you would do

```
curl -I <siteName>.azurewebsites.net
```

you would get this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Wed, 17 Sep 2014 16:57:26 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "2ba0757598d2cf1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=<very long hash>; Path=/;Domain=<siteName>.azurewebsites.net
Date: Fri, 28 Nov 2014 03:13:07 GMT
```

what you are interested in is the `ARRAFinity` if you send couple of request you would notice that hash will keep changing between 2 values that represent your 2 instances.

Set that in your `Cookie` header on your request will guarantee it going to one of the instances and not the other.

```
curl --cookie ARRAfinity=<one of the hashes you got> <siteName>.azurewebsites.net
```

Comment: That did it!  A bit annoying having to mine / manipulate cookies but at the end of the day it wasn't too big a deal.